# PyQt keeps closing most likely due to timer error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextbrowser

I am trying to get a line of text to display in the pyqt4 text browser. I am able to get it to display, but whenever I start to resize the window while I am running the function the PyQt window closes. Currently, it just closes without display errors or anything else. Before it would display this error:

```
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
```

I have tried both .append() and .instertPlainText(). The append is where I got the error from. Thank you for your help, sorry if this is unclear.

Here is my code:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):                                                                               
   def __init__(self, parent=None):                                                                         
      QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)                                                                           
      self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()                                                                          
      self.ui.setupUi(self)
      self.stopAutoRun=0
      self.ui.autoButton.clicked.connect(self.autoRun)
      self.waitTime=.2
   '''
   ________________________________________________________________________________
                                          autoRun
   Description: will continously look for a new JSON file and process it once it appears
  _______________________________________________________
  '''
  def autoRun(self):
     self.task1=threading.Thread(target=self.autoRunThread)                                                                                                        
     self.task1.setDaemon(True)                                                                                                                      
     self.task1.start()

  def autoRunThread(self):
     self.task1=threading.currentThread()
     while getattr(self.task1,"run",True):
        commands=powerSupply.setValuesFile()
        data=powerSupply.readValues()
        self.ui.commandOutput.insertPlainText(str(data))
        time.sleep(self.waitTime)
```

ui:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1270, 805)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_3"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 60, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.openButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.openButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.openButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.openButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("openButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        spacerItem2 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.runButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.runButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.runButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.runButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("runButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        spacerItem3 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.autoButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.autoButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("autoButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.autoButton)
        spacerItem4 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.stopAutoButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopAutoButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopAutoButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stopAutoButton)
        spacerItem5 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.outputButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.outputButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.outputButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.outputButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("\n"
""))
        self.outputButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("outputButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.outputButton)
        spacerItem6 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.powerOffButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.powerOffButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"))
        self.powerOffButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("powerOffButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.powerOffButton)
        spacerItem7 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 10, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem7)
        self.powerButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.powerButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 28))
        self.powerButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 28))
        self.powerButton.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.powerButton.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.powerButton.setStatusTip(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.powerButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"))
        self.powerButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("powerButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.powerButton)
        spacerItem8 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.commandInput = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.commandInput.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 300))
        self.commandInput.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("commandInput"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.commandInput)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.commandOutput = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.commandOutput.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 100))
        self.commandOutput.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("commandOutput"))
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.commandOutput)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1270, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.openButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "manually chose a JSON file to run", None))
        self.openButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File", None))
        self.runButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "runs the chosen JSON file", None))
        self.runButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run File", None))
        self.autoButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "starts to automatically run new JSON files in directory", None))
        self.autoButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Run", None))
        self.stopAutoButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Stops the auto run funtion", None))
        self.stopAutoButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop Auto Run", None))
        self.outputButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "changes where the file is being stored during while this GUI instance is open", None))
        self.outputButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Change Output File", None))
        self.powerOffButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Turns off Voltage output", None))
        self.powerOffButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Voltage Off", None))
        self.powerButton.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Closes Voltage Output and shuts down GUI", None))
        self.powerButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Voltage Off and Exit", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Command Input", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Command Output", None))
```

Comment: what is powerSupply?

Comment: You could share the code of the Ui_MainWindow class.

Comment: it is importing functions from another program. in this case it is just getting data. The program is able to work perfectly fine if i comment out the self.ui.commandOutput.insertPlainText(str(data)), which is why i think it is the reason for the crash

Comment: sure, sorry I didnt think that it would be causing the problem so I didnt think of adding it. Also it has a lot of lines that are unaffected by the program so far.

Comment: I have made some modifications to your code and it does not generate the error. You could share a code that is reproducible and verifiable.

Comment: You could share your code through github, drive or similar to test it.

Comment: see my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread is the only thread where the GUI should be updated, if you want to update any part of the view from another thread you must use the signals, in your case:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):  
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                                                         
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()                                                                          
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.signal.connect(self.ui.commandOutput.insertPlainText)
        [...]

    def autoRun(self):
        [...]

    def autoRunThread(self):
        self.task1=threading.currentThread()
        while getattr(self.task1,"run",True):
            commands=powerSupply.setValuesFile()
            data=powerSupply.readValues()
            self.signal.emit(str(data))
            time.sleep(self.waitTime)
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Comment: Sorry about the code being hard to deal with. I'll try to make it more manageable next time

Comment: For more information read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: For you to ask better questions you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask